# Disable https to http redirect

Tags: html

My site is using HTTPS only.
I allow using BBCodes to show images. Users are placing images like "https://imagehoster.net/img.png" and the imagehoster is using a redirect so the browser loads it via HTTP "http://imagehoster.net/img.png". This makes the browser showing annoying mixed content warnings. Is there a way to prevent this?

Answer (score 1):

Short: NO

Long:
the have no really web server listening to ssl.
in fact, there is only a firewall/proxy which sends a http locate to the browser.
You can't intercept that request. even if you could, where to redirect to?
they don't provide a ssl server, because it takes to much resources for encryption or it takes to much traffic, because proxy#s can't cache.

An idea to solve that problem:
detect those links, download them and store a copy on your server.
replace the link. maybe you need only to store a preview. if the click on it redirect to the original link on a new browser window.